# PHP TCP connection time delay

Tags: javascript, php, tcp

I have a TCP-server running on my raspberry pi which can return me some sensordata, when it receives the command "r".
In telnet this looks like:

> >> r
>
> 123,123,131,321;

I instantly get an answer form the server with telnet. Since I want to view the data from different devices I decided to build a PHP and javascript interface.

In my javascript code I call a PHP methed to read the php method for reading the TCP server:

```
$.ajax('readTCP.php', {
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                drawStatus();
                $('.statustext').text('Status:  ' + data);
            },
            error: function() {
                console.error("fehler")
            }
        });
```

readTCP.php:

```
<?php
    $str = "oi";
    $fp = fsockopen("localhost", 1234, $errno, $errstr, 30);
    if (!$fp) {
        echo "Fehler!";
    } else {
        fwrite($fp, "r");
        $str = fgets ($fp, 1024);
        fclose($fp);
    }
    echo json_encode($str);
?>
```

The problem I have is, that reading the TCP server with this script takes like 45 seconds.

I am no expert on PHP, this might be an obvious mistake, but I cannot figure it out.

Why is it so slow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a simular TCP Client running on my raspberry pi. The difference is that I am using `fread($fp, 20);` instead of `fgets ($fp, 1024);`.

So try this:

```
<?php
    $str = "oi";
    $fp = fsockopen("localhost", 1234, $errno, $errstr, 30);
    if (!$fp) {
        echo "Fehler!";
    } else {
        fwrite($fp, "r");
        $str = fread($fp, 20);
        echo json_encode($str);
        fclose($fp);
    }
?>
```